# Iterating through a directory tree in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-os

I have a set of data that is stored in a directory tree. Data for a given day is in a folder that bares the name of the day (like 01 for the first day, 14 for the fourteenth day in a month, etc.), all folders for days of a given month are stored in a monthly folder (numbers 01 to 12) and all of the month folders are inside a yearly folder (2014, 2015 and 2016 in my case). All of theese are in another folder.

I have defined 3 functions that all iterate throug one folder by using a *for* iterator with *os.listdir()* (but perform somewhat different operations):

```
for e in os.listdir(os.curdir):
    if e.endswith(refer[-4:]:
        #Performs operations (GDAL related)
```

Earlier in the program I have the user input certain parameters including the top folder (which is input into the function via the *os.curdir*) and a reference file (stored in *refer* variable). The functions *return* a variable *arr* that is stored in *out_arr*. In case the user wants to go throug all the data I have this line of code invoke the correct function and go deep enough through the directory tree:

```
elif param_vrsta == "dr" and param_obdobje == "v":
    for dd in os.listdir(os.curdir):
        for aa in os.listdir(dd):
            for kk in os.listdir(aa):
                out_arr = krog1()
```

There are several *elifs* that go one or two or three levels deep before and after and invoke one of the three functions.

But I keep getting an error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Path could not be found: '01'

on the

`for kk in os.listdir(aa):`

line. 
The endgoal is to be able to choose wether to perform the operations on one folder (day), one month (up to 31 folders of data), one year (12 folders with up to 31 folders of data) or just all the data and have the function work every time.
Have I missed some syntax error (or added one too many lines), or am I going about this the wrong way from the getgo?

Comment: May I suggest you use more descriptive variable names such as yearly_dir, monthly_dir, daily_dir, ... ?

Comment: @RoelSchroeven: I suspect that we'd find these names more familiar if we spoke Slovenian.

Comment: @BillBell: possibly yes. I didn't think of that since I'm used to seeing code mostly in English even in non-English speaking countries.

Comment: I'm sorry, I used terms that are closer to me (and yes some are Slovenian), but the ones you reffered to are just letters (one or two), the directories are reffered to by *e, kk, aa* and *dd* wich have no meaning (they are like x, y, z). @Roel Schroeven

Comment: @RoelSchroeven: This whole thing was meant to be seen slightly ironically anyway! ;) We have participants living in three countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not say that you're doing anything wrong. I think there's an *easier* way.

Consider this folder structure that is truncated in comparison to what you have.

[image: folders]

Each of the lowest level folders contains just one file called data.txt.

Once you set `Path` to the top-level path name you can get an iterator to various subsets of the files under that path.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path

>>> path = Path('temp/')
```

All of the files:

```
>>> list(path.glob('*/*/*'))
[WindowsPath('temp/01/01/data.txt'), WindowsPath('temp/01/02/data.txt'), WindowsPath('temp/02/01/data.txt'), WindowsPath('temp/02/02/data.txt'), WindowsPath('temp/03/01/data.txt'), WindowsPath('temp/03/02/data.txt')]
```

All of the February files:

```
>>> list(path.glob('02/*/*'))
[WindowsPath('temp/02/01/data.txt'), WindowsPath('temp/02/02/data.txt')]
```

All of the files for the second day of the month:

```
>>> list(path.glob('*/02/*'))
[WindowsPath('temp/01/02/data.txt'), WindowsPath('temp/02/02/data.txt'), WindowsPath('temp/03/02/data.txt')]
```

All of the files for the second day of February:

```
>>> list(path.glob('02/02/*'))
[WindowsPath('temp/02/02/data.txt')]
```

**Edit**: Supplementary:

```
from pathlib import Path

top_path = input('Please input the full name of the top path:')
path = Path(top_path)
year = input('What year do you want to consider? (Enter * for all years)')
month = input('What month do you want to consider? (Enter * for all months)')
day = input('What day do you want to consider? (Enter * for all days)')

for item in path.glob('{}/{}/{}'.format(year, month, day)):
    <do something with item here>
```

Comment: This really looks easier, but can I exchange the string in the *path.glob()* brackets with variables containing user input or at least a call to a list containing possibilities for locations?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Please see the edit. What's more, I've found from playing with pathlib in connection with the documentation that it offers many useful features over other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should seriously consider the approach of Bill Bell's answer, but for completeness here's what (I think) is the cause of the error you get: os.listdir returns unqualified file names, so when you dig deeper into the directory hierarchy you need to specify each directory along the way.

Something like this:

```
for year_dir in os.listdir(os.curdir):
    year_dir = os.path.join(os.curdir, year_dir)
    for month_dir in os.listdir(year_dir):
        month_dir = os.path.join(os.year_dir, month_dir)
        for day_dir in os.listdir(month_dir):
            ...
```

Alternatives:

- Use glob.glob() instead of os.listdir(): glob does qualify the file names
- Use recursive glob, possibly in combination with pathlib.Path (as in Bill Bell's answer)
- Use os.walk()

Comment: I added the lines you suggested, but all it seems to do is change the last part of the Error Message to '\\01' instead of just '01'. There is something else going on. How would the glob or os.walk work? I tried using walk but all the data is output as a set of lists I don't know how to input into the function to work, nor how to control what maps to use and what not to.

Comment: I'd try to insert print(year_dir), print(month_dir) and so on before the calls to os.listdir(). That way you can see exactly what paths are passed, and possibly give a clue to the cause of the problem.

Comment: It crashes after it prints the month folder. It's also unusual (to me anyway) that it outputs with a dot '.'. It outputs '.\01'.

Comment: The dot comes from os.curdir. Why it crashes, I have no idea. What is the traceback?

Comment: WinError 2 or 3

Comment: Can you post the full traceback (perhaps edit your question)? That's a lot more helpful.

Comment: Before it was: "The directory name is not valid." on the same line as in my original post. Now I get NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: '.\\test_12014.tif' I assume, this error occurs due to extra files that aren't folders and cannot be opend and listed. The file listed is an output file of my program.